# How to add eventlisteners after simple get request json in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, jquery-hover

Ok so I am experimenting with Angular but I have run into a problem and maybe it is because I haven't adopted the Angular way of thinking yet, but this is basically what I ran into.

I get some data with a JSON request and show this data in a list using ng-repeat. So far so good. No errors in the console, but it does not attach the eventlistener to the ng-repeat elements. The code is fine, because with non ng-repeat elements it works like a charm. Someone else ran into this problem and how did you solve it? Thanks in advance.

```
   <div ng-controller="basictrl">
       <h1>Lijst van producten</h1>
        <ul ng-repeat="item in producten">
        <li>{{item.naam}}</li>
        <li>{{item.prijs}}</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

JS

```
    angular.module("app", ['ngRoute'])

      .controller("basictrl", function ($scope, $http, producteffecten) {
         $scope.producten = null;
         $http({
             method: 'GET',
             url: 'producten.json'
         }).
         success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
             $scope.producten = data;
             $scope.showdescription = producteffecten.showdescription; 
         }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {});


     })

  .factory('producteffecten', function() {
    var effecten = {};
      effecten.showdescription = $('ul').hover(function (){
         $(this).append("<p>Test</p>");
      });

   return effecten;   
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is: you can use $('ul').on("hover",function(){}). But this is not the angular way of thinking. The first improvement you could make is this:

1. add ng-mouseover="muisOverEffectje()" to the ul in the html
2. add $scope.muisOverEffectje=function(){ your event code} to the angular page

The next step to avoid adding the code with jquery to make it even more angular could be something like this:

1. add a parameter which gives the selected item to your event  : muisOverEffectje(item)
2. add ng-show="showDescription" to the the ul
3. put show-description to true in the event handler

The last step could be: Make a directive for you . Like a product component for example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I still don't know why it is not working correctly. I got it to work with a little tweak, but it is ugly. I will have to force myself thinking differently while working with Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a timeout works, but it is hacky I guess. I will try to rewrite in a more angular way.

```
.factory('producteffecten', function() {
        var effecten = {};
    //SETTING TIMEOUT WORKS SOMEHOW
          effecten.showdescription = setTimeout(function() {

              $('ul').hover(function (){
             $(this).append("<p>Test</p>");
          });

          }, 10);

       return effecten;   
      })
```

Comment: Don't do DOM manipulation in factory. use directive to manipulate DOM

Comment: @MarkSmit: Yeah, I don't know all the ins and outs yet so I easily go back to pure Js/jQuery. But I was about to throw the whole factory thing out anyway. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mikey once you  get to know angular.. you probably don't want to g back to pure js or jquery. But it's hard in the start specially if u did jquery before.

Answer (score 0):

You could also write an directive. Which is the nicest way in angular to do this kind of stuff:

**Html:**

```
  <div ng-controller="basictrl">
       <h1>Lijst van producten</h1>
        <ul ng-repeat="item in producten" hover-text="item.effect">
        <li>{{item.naam}}</li>
        <li>{{item.prijs}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**js:**

```
  .controller("basictrl", function ($scope, $http, producteffecten) {
     $scope.producten = null;
     $http({
         method: 'GET',
         url: 'producten.json'
     }).
     success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
         $scope.producten = data;
         $scope.showdescription = producteffecten.showdescription; 
     }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {});
    })

    .directive("hoverText",function(){

        return {link:function(scope,elem,attr){
            var insertElem=$("<div class='hovertext'>"+scope.hoverText+"</div>")
            elem  .mouseenter(function() {
                    insertElem.appendTo(elem);
              })
              .mouseleave(function() {
                    insertElem.remove();
              });
        },
        scope:{"hoverText":"="}
        };
    });
```